# ODS PACKAGE publish email does not send emails

Tags: sas, zip, sas-ods

**SAS EG / SAS 9.4**

I am currently using `ODS package` to zip a few files and then send them over to recipients using `filename email`. 
I recently came through the [ODS user guide](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/65308/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p19kppnlyy01n7n18jcfsy0eutvq.htm) (see `EMAIL PROPERTIES`) that says we can publish the archive to email addresses.

I am using the below snippet - *(I've used `libname` and `filename` statements)*

```
ods package (proem) open nopf;
ods package (proem) add file=a1;
ods package (proem) add file=a2;
ods package (proem) add file=a3;
ods package (proem) add file=a4;
ods package (proem) add file=a5;
ods package (proem) publish email   
    addresses ("xyz@company.com")
    properties (archive_name="Products2Email.zip" archive_path="%sysfunc(pathname(crap))");
ods package (proem) close;
```

The above code creates the zip file in the designated path, but doesn't deliver it to the email address provided. The zip file, that gets created, is a little less than 1 MB in size, and I am able to send it via a data step using `filename email` statement.

Is there something that needs to be changed or checked, or is it that I am wrong in interpreting the ODS user guide?

Comment: What’s in the log, any errors or interesting notes?

Comment: @Quentin None at all! Just one stating that SAS is writing PROEM to the path mentioned.